# Div is positioned lower in Firefox than in other browsers

Tags: css

I've got a cart drawer that slides in from the side and multiple divs in it for products. One of the divs is positioned lower in Firefox and it overflows its container but it's all fine in other browsers (Chrome, Opera, IE, Edge). I can't tell what causes it since I don't even have any positioning done on it other than a margin-left of 10px. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float your cart image to the left

```
header .cart-container #drawer-products .product-elements {
float: left;
}
```

and then clear this div by adding float left and width 100%

```
header .cart-container #drawer-products #drawer-indiv-product {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

adding these changes will make both firefox and chrome carts look the same